# How does a process and its children use memory in case of mmap()?

Tags: process, c, fork, shared-memory

Let's say, we are creating a shared memory using mmap(). Let's say the total memory size is 4096. If we use a fork() system call to create children, would the children use the same memory, or will need to have their own memory to work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding MMAP](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389124/understanding-mmap)

Comment: I think the answer says that every process has its own virtual address space. My question is: If a process uses fork() to create another process, does the child gets to use the memory we allocated for the parent, or do we need to use MAP_SHARED to do that?

Comment: I think this is a very poor question, because when reading "man mmap", you'll find: "*Memory mapped by mmap() is preserved across fork(2), with the same attributes.*".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On [`fork()`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) the memory space of the parent process is cloned into the child process. As an optimization, modern operating systems use COW (copy on write), so all private memory is shared with the child process until one of the processes performs a change. Then the affected memory pages get duplicated.

> The child process and the parent process run in separate memory
> spaces.  At the time of fork() both memory spaces have the same
> content.  Memory writes, file mappings (mmap(2)), and unmappings
> (munmap(2)) performed by one of the processes do not affect the
> other.

"Both memory spaces have the same content" includes memory allocated with [`mmap()`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html). The memory mappings get cloned and `mmap()` or `munmap()` after the fork don't affect the other process anymore.

Only memory mapped with `MAP_SHARED` (or the Linux-specific `MAP_SHARED_VALIDATE`) before the fork will have changes to the contents propagated between the processes.

> MAP_SHARED
> Share this mapping.  Updates to the mapping are visible to other processes
> mapping the same region, and (in the case of file-backed mappings) are
> carried through to the underlying file.  (To precisely control when updates
> are carried through to the underlying file requires the use of msync(2).)

There are some Linux specific mapping flags to modify the behaviour in other ways:

> - Memory mappings that have been marked with the madvise(2) MADV_DONTFORK flag are not inherited across a fork().
> - Memory in address ranges that have been marked with the madvise(2)
>   MADV_WIPEONFORK flag is zeroed in the child after a
>   fork().  (The MADV_WIPEONFORK setting remains in place for
>   those address ranges in the child.)

On [`exec()`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) the memory image is replaced with the new process, so all memory mappings that got inherited on `fork()` are removed.

> All process attributes are preserved during an execve(), except the following:
>     […]
>
> - Memory mappings are not preserved (mmap(2)).
> - Attached System V shared memory segments are detached (shmat(2)).
> - POSIX shared memory regions are unmapped (shm_open(3)).

Comment: This helps a lot. Thank you!

Comment: @unixgeek If my response answered your question, please mark it as "accepted" by clicking on the checkmark on the left of my answer. Thanks!